# (unknown): #2514: An unknown error occurred when fetching the script. [Service Workers]

Tags: javascript, debugging, service-worker

Here's what's on console:

```
(unknown): #2514: An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.  [Service Workers]
```

I am get the above error on my dev console when the service-worker has taken over or skipped waiting and I reload the page with the network turned off. The thing is I get plenty of fetch errors on the console because obviously none of the requests are passing through but there is just one error on SW dev console (Click image):

[image]

What is it about?

The error message itself isn't telling much about the issue, like the request it bailed out on or similar.

Comment: Running into the same error. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I thought it was somehow related to the request `**/serviceworker.js` itself not completing. Yeah, that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add your corresponding https certificate in your browser.
for chrome
go to setting -> advanced settings -> manage ssl certificates

under authorities tab click import then add your .crt file. 
restart browser it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was testing a .NET Core application locally and in my config builder I had UseUrls in my Program.cs setting my localhost url with http instead of https. I was trying to load my service worker script from https.