# Error 8280:An unknown error occurred while fetching the script in service Workers

Tags: javascript, service-worker, offline-caching, progressive-web-apps

I am basically caching an offline page and loading it when my website is offline.

For this I have created a page say 'signIn' and the javascript file of 'SignIn' is javascript->pages->signIn here I have initiated the service worker like

javascript/page/script.js

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw1.js').then(function(reg){
       console.log("Service workers registered");
     });
 }

else{

   console.log("Browser doesnt support service workers");
}

})
```

The sw1.js and the offline.html is basically in the same folder as the page SignIn.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {

  var offlineRequest = new Request('./offline.html');
  event.waitUntil(
    fetch(offlineRequest).then(function(response) {
      return caches.open('offline').then(function(cache) {
        console.log('[oninstall] Cached offline page', response.url);
        return cache.put(offlineRequest, response);
      });
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

  var request = event.request;

  if (request.method === 'GET') {
  console.log(request);
    event.respondWith(
      fetch(request).then(function(response){
          console.log("From Network "+response);
          return response;
      }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log(
        '[onfetch] Failed. Serving cached offline fallback ' +
          error
         );
        return caches.open('offline').then(function(cache) {
           console.log("Opened Cache");
          return cache.match('./offline.html');
        });
      })


    );
  }

});
```

Basically things work fine when I am online but When i am offline I get the following error in chrome-dev-tools-applications .
Please Help me.

Comment: BTW when I click on offline of the Service Worker panel and reload ,My previous cache is lost.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865126/unknown-2514-an-unknown-error-occurred-when-fetching-the-script-service-w