# All service workers fail to register with "TypeError: An unknown error occurred when fetching the script." – but only on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

My copy of Google Chrome, on my laptop, fails to register all service workers. If I load any website that has offline functionality, devtools console outputs:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/') with script ('https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/service-worker.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
```

Note that the above error is from `https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/`, which is a technology demonstration *made by google, specifically about service workers, specifically for chrome*, not something I created. One other interesting thing is that service workers fetched from localhost can be registered with no problem. This would suggest an SSL issue (I think), but then again the host of the above website is github pages (is there any way my browser could be not trusting github pages? I haven't found any evidence to support that).

I get the same error if I directly type `navigator.serviceWorker.register("https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/service-worker.js");` into the console on the same site.

It's not just a console message: if I load the website, then disconnect from the internet, then refresh the page, the browser reports "no internet" and does not load the website. The same thing happens if I use devtools>Application>Service Workers offline mode. This indicates that the service worker is failing to register. However, the Service Workers devtools tab does show service workers present – it just lists them as "redundant" instead of "active and running". Bizarrely, the "time received" is 1970-01-01.

[image: image of service worker status in devtools]

I'm using Google Chrome `Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)` on MacOS Big Sur. On other browsers (Safari, Firefox, and any browser on any other computer/mobile device), this error does not occur. I have restarted my Chrome multiple times since I first noticed the error, and updated it once since then. Neither fixed it.

I'm aware of a couple similar SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865126/unknown-2514-an-unknown-error-occurred-when-fetching-the-script-service-w) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555311/an-unknown-error-occurred-when-fetching-the-script-service-worker) for example), but all of them have accepted answers about how the website creators can fix bugs in their site. This bug is appearing on websites I did not create, and seems specific to my browser (which I haven't tampered with in any way). The main reason this is driving me nuts is that I really really like Chrome's devtools, and I would like to use them for a current PWA project.

If anyone familiar with Chrome's inner workings knows what could be causing this, or if anyone has solved this in the past, I will be forever in your debt.

Comment: Try disabling any extensions you have on chrome, or try accessing the site in a private window that has no extensions. Maybe they're interfering somehow? The site works for me on Chrome.

Comment: @Nisala Oh my god, that was it!! I had the extension noScript, which blocks javascript. It was turned off, but when I fiddled with the settings, it wasn't responding. I disabled and re-enabled it in settings and now everything is fine. Thank you so, so much. I feel like an idiot, but a happy idiot.